# How does the summing function, together with ORDER BY in the OVER() clause, calculate the subtotal of each window in the following code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions

We need to write the following query:
*Write a query that returns the `sales_date`, `brand`, `quantity`, and running total of monthly sales aliased as `running_total_quantity`.*

Table:

| sales_date | brand | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-31 | Apple | 50 |
| 2022-02-28 | Apple | 40 |
| 2022-03-31 | Apple | 25 |
| 2022-04-30 | Apple | 30 |
| 2022-05-31 | Apple | 47 |
| 2022-06-30 | Apple | 40 |

The right code is:

```
SELECT sales_date, brand, quantity, SUM(quantity) OVER(ORDER BY sales_date) AS running_total_quantity
FROM apple_sales_quantity_by_month
```

Output:

```
| sales_date |  brand   | quantity | running_total_quantity | 
| ---------- | -------- | -------- | ---------------------- |
| 2022-01-31 |  Apple   |   50     |          50            |
| 2022-02-28 |  Apple   |   40     |          90            |
| 2022-03-31 |  Apple   |   25     |          115           |
| 2022-04-30 |  Apple   |   30     |          145           |
| 2022-05-31 |  Apple   |   47     |          192           |
| 2022-06-30 |  Apple   |   40     |          232           |
```

But I don’t understand how using the operator `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause leads to the calculation of INTERMEDIATE totals. I thought `ORDER BY` just sorts the data by date and the sum function adds the sorted data together.
I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me exactly **how the subtotals in this problem are calculated step by step**.
Or is it just a special ability of the `ORDER BY` operator to sum up subtotals that appears when using window functions? In general, I would be grateful for any explanation!

I tried to write code without `ORDER BY`, using other window functions, but here the optimal solution would be to use `ORDER BY`, I would like to understand exactly how it works here.

Comment: The fine [manual about window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to understand what do you mean exactly. From the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

"When an aggregate function is used as a window function, it aggregates over the rows within the current row's window frame. An aggregate used with `ORDER BY` and the default window frame definition produces a “running sum” type of behavior, which may or may not be what's wanted. To obtain aggregation over the whole partition, omit `ORDER BY` or use `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`. Other frame specifications can be used to obtain other effects."